# ROS and MoveIt noetic on ubuntu runs very slow in my MacBook pro

Tags: battery, macbook, ros

I installed Ubuntu from virtual box, and then ROS and Moveit Noetic because I need to do a robotics project. However, it's been like 2 weeks and I have been searching for a solution because as soon as I open Rviz, my MacBook starts to consume a lot of battery (probably like 2% per minute of battery). My computer is fast, 16GB RAM, 500GB storage, and never had issues with it. It only acts weird when I open Rviz. Not sure about the issue, but ubuntu is also kind of slow when I open Firefox as well. The problem is when I use scale mode or bigger scale than x200. Please help.

Comment: You've provided no release details. What version of Ubuntu, no details of how you installed ROS, nor Move....   ie. please provide some specific details, specific messages rather than vague "*acts weird*"  (did you look in logs for your *unstated* Ubuntu product, what did you see etc).

Comment: A few assertions are begging to be commented about: (1) *My computer is fast, 16GB RAM, 500GB storage* The amount of RAM or storage has nothing to do with speed. More RAM means that you can have more programs running simultaneously and more storage means that you can install more stuff and save more stuff, nothing else. "500GB" tell us nothing about the actual speed. Actually the round number tells us that it's probably an HDD so nowadays slow by definition, especially for running the OS and software, SSDs now being the standard. (...)

Comment: (...) (2) *I installed Ubuntu from virtual box* (actually (Oracle) Virtualbox and *with* like in a Virtualbox's virtual machine, not from) It tells nothing about the Ubuntu VM's settings (how many CPU cores, how much assigned RAM, etc.) so, even if the host computer is fast or good enough, a VM can be sluggish depending on the assigned resources. And if you're running a VM on top of an host OS running in a HDD then it'll be SLOW no matter what. Furthermore ROS itself has high system requirements about graphics and stuff. In a VM you never get the same resources as the host OS, obviously (...)

Comment: (...) One obvious "handicap" of virtualization is actually graphics. No software requiring a specific minimum graphics subsystem can possibly work fine in a VM where all the hardware isn't "real" but virtual. That is probably the main reason for your perceived slowness.